# Read data points and plot an airfoil

Tags: matlab, plot

This is the program I'm trying to create (very new to Matlab).
I have the main program that is using airfoil geometry to calculate pressure distribution and use the pressure distribution later on in other equations.

So far: I have generated equation for NACA 4 and 5 series airfoil based on the input series number from the user.
However, I want another option to have user generate their own x and y coordinates of the airfoil and I need to be able to use those values in the program.

```
function [xs]=FSP()
%closes all windows, clears everything
writeofile=0;


fprintf('\n');
fprintf('Enter option: 1= 4 series, 2=5 series 3= upload');

if ~nargin
    option = input ('\n select option:');
    if option ==1
        FourDigit=input('\n Type in NACA 4 series: ');
        alpha = input ('\n Type in angle of attack in degree: ');
    elseif option ==2
        FiveDigit= input('\n Type in NACA 5 series: ');
        alpha = input ('\n Type in angle of attack in degree: ');
    elseif option ==3
       %
       % 
    end 
end
N=100; % Number of points generated.

if option == 1
    [x,y]= Airfoil4 (N,N,FourDigit);
%    [xmid,ymid,Cp]=HessSmithPanel (x,y,alpha);
%    [xU,yU,CpU]=UpperSurface (xmid,ymid,Cp,N);
elseif option ==2 
       [x,y]= Airfoil5 (N,N,FiveDigit);
%    [xmid,ymid,Cp]=HessSmithPanel (x,y,alpha);
%    [xU,yU,CpU]=UpperSurface (xmid,ymid,Cp,N);
elseif option ==3

end

figure
plot (x,y);
axis([-.1 1.1 -.4 .4]);
```

That is part of the main program that is currently working for 4 and 5 series, it gets the x and y coordinates in an array and plots them for future usage. I need the third option of data collection working similar to that.

This is an example of NACA 5 series

```
function [x,y]=Airfoil5(nU,nL,NACA)
xU=zeros(nU,1);
cU=zeros(nU,1);
dcU=zeros(nU,1);
betaU=zeros(nU,1);
xL=zeros(nL,1);
cL=zeros(nL,1);
dcL=zeros(nL,1);
betaL=zeros(nL,1);

L=floor(NACA/10000);
P=floor(NACA/1000)-L*100;
R=floor(NACA/100)-L*100-P*10;
XX=NACA-L*10000-P*1000-R*100;

maxt=XX/100;
xf=P/20;
Cli=3*L/20;
%cmax=cmax*.01;
%pcmax=pcmax*.1;
%maxt=maxt*.01;

syms m;
sol=solve(xf==m*(1-sqrt(m/3)),m);
m = double(real(sol(2)));


Q=(3*m-7*m^2+8*m^3-4*m^4)/sqrt(m*(1-m))-3/2*(1-2*m)*(pi/2-asin(1-2*m));
k1=6*Cli/Q;

if R == 0
    for i=1:nU
        xU(i)=.5*(1-cos(pi*(i-1)/nU));
    end
    for i=1:nL
        xL(i)=.5*(1+cos(pi*(i-1)/nL));
    end

    tU=5*maxt*(.2969*sqrt(xU)-xU.*(.126+xU.*(.35372-xU.*(.2843-xU*.1015))));
    tL=5*maxt*(.2969*sqrt(xL)-xL.*(.126+xL.*(.35372-xL.*(.2843-xL*.1015))));

    for i=1:nU
        if xU(i)<m
            cU(i)=(k1/6)*(xU(i)*xU(i)*xU(i)-3*m*xU(i)*xU(i)+m^2*(3-m)*xU(i));
            dcU(i)=(k1/6)*(3*xU(i)*xU(i)-6*m*xU(i)+m^2*(3-m));
        else
            cU(i)=k1*m^3*(1-xU(i))/6;
            dcU(i)=-k1*m^3/6;
        end
        betaU=atan(dcU);
    end
    for i=1:nL
        if xL(i)<m
            cL(i)=(k1/6)*(xL(i)*xL(i)*xL(i)-3*m*xL(i)*xL(i)+m^2*(3-m)*xL(i));
            dcL(i)=(k1/6)*(3*xL(i)*xL(i)-6*m*xL(i)+m^2*(3-m));
        else
            cL(i)=k1*m^3*(1-xL(i))/6;
            dcL(i)=-k1*m^3/6;
        end
        betaL=atan(dcL);
    end
else
    k2=(3*(0.217-.15)^2-0.217^3)/(1-0.217)^3;

    for i=1:nU
        xU(i)=.5*(1-cos(pi*(i-1)/nU));
    end
    for i=1:nL
        xL(i)=.5*(1+cos(pi*(i-1)/nL));
    end

    tU=5*maxt*(.2969*sqrt(xU)-xU.*(.126+xU.*(.35372-xU.*(.2843-xU*.1015))));
    tL=5*maxt*(.2969*sqrt(xL)-xL.*(.126+xL.*(.35372-xL.*(.2843-xL*.1015))));

    for i=1:nU
        if xU(i)<m
            cU(i)=(k1/6)*((xU(i)-m)^3-k2*(1-m)^3*xU(i)-m^3*xU(i)+m^3);
            dcU(i)=(k1/6)*(3*(xU(i)-m)^2-k2*(1-m)^3-m^3);
        else
            cU(i)=(k1/6)*(k2*(xU(i)-m)^3-k2*(1-m)^3*xU(i)-m^3*xU(i)+m^3);
            dcU(i)=(k1/6)*(3*k2*(xU(i)-m)^2-k2*(1-m)^3-m^3);
        end
        betaU=atan(dcU);
    end
    for i=1:nL
        if xL(i)<m

            cL(i)=(k1/6)*((xL(i)-m)^3-k2*(1-m)^3*xL(i)-m^3*xL(i)+m^3);
            dcL(i)=(k1/6)*(3*(xL(i)-m)^2-k2*(1-m)^3-m^3);
        else
            cL(i)=(k1/6)*(k2*(xL(i)-m)^3-k2*(1-m)^3*xL(i)-m^3*xL(i)+m^3);
            dcL(i)=(k1/6)*(3*k2*(xL(i)-m)^2-k2*(1-m)^3-m^3);        
        end
        betaL=atan(dcL);
    end
end


x=xL+tL.*sin(betaL);
y=cL-tL.*cos(betaL);
x=[x;xU-tU.*sin(betaU);x(1)];
y=[y;cU+tU.*cos(betaU);y(1)];
```

So I need the third option to develop similarly like NACA 5 series and store the data from the text file into the variable x and y.

Here is the text file.

```
AG19
     0.999992    0.000244
     0.994067    0.000848
     0.982082    0.002113
     0.968544    0.003504
     0.954708    0.004914
     0.940826    0.006276
     0.926943    0.007613
     0.913056    0.008933
     0.899168    0.010245
     0.885282    0.011547
     0.871396    0.012840
     0.857515    0.014123
     0.843633    0.015399
     0.829754    0.016658
     0.815876    0.017909
     0.801995    0.019144
     0.788118    0.020364
     0.774240    0.021567
     0.760358    0.022757
     0.746480    0.023934
     0.732598    0.025098
     0.718714    0.026246
     0.704832    0.027382
     0.690952    0.028505
     0.677070    0.029611
     0.663191    0.030702
     0.649316    0.031769
     0.635436    0.032803
     0.621559    0.033813
     0.607686    0.034792
     0.593811    0.035742
     0.579936    0.036661
     0.566066    0.037549
     0.552198    0.038403
     0.538328    0.039225
     0.524462    0.040010
     0.510601    0.040760
     0.496741    0.041474
     0.482880    0.042149
     0.469025    0.042788
     0.455177    0.043387
     0.441328    0.043948
     0.427484    0.044466
     0.413649    0.044946
     0.399815    0.045383
     0.385986    0.045776
     0.372169    0.046125
     0.358355    0.046428
     0.344545    0.046682
     0.330750    0.046887
     0.316965    0.047037
     0.303185    0.047134
     0.289421    0.047171
     0.275674    0.047146
     0.261933    0.047054
     0.248213    0.046888
     0.234514    0.046643
     0.220830    0.046310
     0.207177    0.045881
     0.193554    0.045344
     0.179962    0.044689
     0.166424    0.043904
     0.152931    0.042974
     0.139504    0.041884
     0.126159    0.040617
     0.112901    0.039151
     0.099774    0.037462
     0.086793    0.035521
     0.074020    0.033292
     0.061500    0.030726
     0.049351    0.027778
     0.037754    0.024395
     0.027090    0.020576
     0.018069    0.016536
     0.011377    0.012750
     0.006933    0.009581
     0.004065    0.007011
     0.002186    0.004880
     0.000960    0.003044
     0.000235    0.001406
     0.000001   -0.000094
     0.000368   -0.001552
     0.001471   -0.002908
     0.003259   -0.004084
     0.005777   -0.005206
     0.009368   -0.006368
     0.014713   -0.007619
     0.022632   -0.008896
     0.033028   -0.009988
     0.044948   -0.010773
     0.057612   -0.011265
     0.070626   -0.011515
     0.083847   -0.011575
     0.097208   -0.011488
     0.110664   -0.011286
     0.124193   -0.010995
     0.137773   -0.010634
     0.151402   -0.010216
     0.165062   -0.009753
     0.178754   -0.009253
     0.192471   -0.008724
     0.206209   -0.008174
     0.219965   -0.007607
     0.233740   -0.007028
     0.247527   -0.006440
     0.261333   -0.005847
     0.275149   -0.005250
     0.288979   -0.004652
     0.302827   -0.004054
     0.316687   -0.003459
     0.330560   -0.002868
     0.344449   -0.002282
     0.358351   -0.001705
     0.372267   -0.001137
     0.386195   -0.000582
     0.400136   -0.000039
     0.414079    0.000487
     0.428014    0.000997
     0.441936    0.001488
     0.455848    0.001958
     0.469754    0.002410
     0.483648    0.002838
     0.497536    0.003246
     0.511417    0.003632
     0.525297    0.003999
     0.539171    0.004338
     0.553041    0.004649
     0.566907    0.004932
     0.580771    0.005183
     0.594629    0.005404
     0.608483    0.005597
     0.622333    0.005758
     0.636177    0.005888
     0.650015    0.005989
     0.663852    0.006060
     0.677688    0.006098
     0.691521    0.006104
     0.705354    0.006082
     0.719189    0.006029
     0.733027    0.005945
     0.746863    0.005833
     0.760702    0.005691
     0.774544    0.005518
     0.788385    0.005316
     0.802230    0.005089
     0.816081    0.004833
     0.829932    0.004550
     0.843784    0.004242
     0.857640    0.003908
     0.871495    0.003551
     0.885353    0.003171
     0.899212    0.002768
     0.913070    0.002347
     0.926931    0.001903
     0.940790    0.001439
     0.954652    0.000956
     0.968488    0.000451
     0.982076   -0.000064
     0.994074   -0.000511
     1.000008   -0.000710
```

The text file generally contains the name of the airfoil and then the columns of x coordinate and y coordinate. I need to be able to take each of this coordinate and save them in the array x and y variable like I have it in the airfoil5 function. I also need to have the N variable in the FSP funcction to be changed to the number of x-y coordinates that are coming in from the airfoil text file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the `importdata` function. You could easily read that file format with

```
data=importdata('/path/to/file/filename.txt', ' ', 1);
N=size(data,1);
x=data(:,1);
y=data(:,2);
```